# How can i import the csv files (other than prestashop entity) into prestashop?

Tags: csv, import, prestashop

how can i import the csv files into prestahop. I searched so many things and known about the import tool in prestashop. but i want to import csv files for my own tables and not the default prestashop entity. am new to prestashop, can anyone help me how to import a csv file to separate module and get the values of those csv file. help me ..

Answer (score 0):

You will first have to convert the csv file to sql file. Try this [online converter](http://www.convertcsvtomysql.com/).

After the conversion, don't go to Back Office of your website. Instead, Go to the cPanel of your hosting and go to phpMyAdmin. Select your database and you will see "Import."

Answer (score 0):

You will need to upload the csv file and then process the csv file. Take all the data and arrange it according to the PS database. Then you will need to insert those arranged that to related tables. It is the only way you can import your data to PS.

Hope this will help you.

Thank you